# How to create a custom NIS map?

Tags: nis

I'd like to create a custom NIS map in order to be able to look up my own information using `ypmatch` and map between local and centralised usernames. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

First off, edit `/var/yp/Makefile` to add in the new map. You’ve probably got something like this:

```
PASSWD = $(YPPWDDIR)/passwd
```

We need to add a new line for the new map. This is going to be the new username map, so call it usermap.

```
USERMAP = $(YPSRCDIR)/usermap
```

`YPSRCDIR` is `/etc` in my case, but obviously choose the path that suits you the best.

Now find a line that starts `all:`. This is the list of maps to update. Add your new map to the end, so it’ll be something like

```
all: auto.home auto.master group hosts netgrp passwd usermap
```

Further down where there is a group of lines like this:

```
passwd:         passwd.byname passwd.byuid
```

you should add in your own map:

```
usermap : usermap.byname
```

The `byname` part is an indicator for what the map key is and isn’t that important for us.

You now need to add a section to tell the makefile how to update your map:

```
usermap.byname: $(USERMAP) $(YPDIR)/Makefile
        @echo "Updating $@..."
        @$(AWK) -F: '!/^[-+#]/ { if ($$1 != "" && $$2 != "" ) \
                print $$1"\t"$$2 }' $(USERMAP) \
                | $(DBLOAD) -i $(USERMAP) -o $(YPMAPDIR)/$@ - $@
        -@$(NOPUSH) || $(YPPUSH) -d $(DOMAIN) $@
```

This processes the file `/etc/usermap` and generates the map file. Essentially you just need to print `key\tvalue` into `$(DBLOAD) …`. This example extracts data from the file assuming it is in the format `key:value`.

Now edit `/var/yp/nicknames` to add your new map:

```
usermap    usermap.byname
```

then run `make` in `/var/yp` as normal.

If you have a slave server you’ll probably have a timeout with the new map at this point. To get round this, you need to run `ypxfr` on the slave to get the map first:

```
/usr/lib/yp/ypxfr -d <yp domain> -h <yp master host> usermap.byname
```